# How to convert counter status to some non-electrical quantity, so that I can see the status without power supply

Tags: power-supply

When I place the instrument in the central unit, it'll get power and increment the counter by 1. But when that instrument is removed from the central unit it has to display what was the last count. When the instrument is removed from the central unit, it will not have power. So how you can decide, how many times the instrument is used? Is there any mechanism by which I can convert my counter status to some non-electrical quantity?

Comment: Yes there is. As an example you could build a printer into the instrument.

Comment: @brian instrument should be very small in size.

Comment: Size wasn't one of the constraints we were asked about. However there are some pretty small printers. Unless you tell us the constraints, we can't make the best suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

An [electro mechanical counter](http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Electrical/ProductsandServices/AutomationandControl/CountControlProducts/Totalizers/Electromechanical/index.htm) maybe?

That's a common way for equipment run time or number of uses to be tracked.

Comment: if we look at cost,is it fair solution?

Answer (score 2):

A common way with modern electronics is to design a small serial EEPROM into the instrument. Then an MCU in either the instrument or in the central unit detects the insertion and startup of the instrument. It increments the counter which is stored in the serial EEPROM by first reading it out, incrementing and then storing back the new count. This takes care of how the count is kept track of in a non-volatile way.

Then for case where you need to "see" the count that is stored in the instrument you can design a small ancillary piece of equipment that possibly has a battery and a small LCD module. This device would connect to the instrument to just read and display the count value that is stored in the serial EEPROM without changing its count value.

This solution works well for many systems because it is common that there are many instruments and it is not necessary to directly be able to see the "count" on each one at the same time.